# M2 - EE (Cloud) - DB Read only?

Tags: magento2, database, cloud

I work for a company that is going to use Magento2 Cloud Enterprise Edition. ( e-commerce website currently on development)
Someone told me while deploying the source code, the database is locked and is on read only access. Is it true ?

I don't find any documentation about this on Magento docs. I found how to do a master / slave on EE ( not available on Cloud) but I really need to know if its true because it will change a lot for the architecture on AWS for me.

Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have confused between read-only for filesystem and read-only for database.

For file-system, you have read only permission (e.g. you can not edit or create new file after SSH'ed on the server).

For database, you do have write permission for the master database. They are introducing slave database (which is a replica of the master database - but use as read-only for performance improvement).

**Update for the bit I missed about DURING the deployment**

During deployment (which inclusive of build phase and deploy phase) - the whole server will be unavailable during the deploy phase. If you have done a few tricks here and there according to the documentation - you can reduce the deploy phase to 1-2 minutes. But there will always be downtime during a deployment.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I was mainly talking about the deployment process. So you can assure me that during deployment the database is read AND write permissions ?

Comment: During deployment, your setup script will be able to write and read from the database. Are you having an external system connected to the Magento database and concern about this connection during deployment?

Comment: Hi thx you very much for your answer :) No it s just someone told me that the database was read - only on deployment. So I was thinking about how am i being able to sell products / or even register customer on my website if the database is read-only but as the databse is read and write during deployment its all good :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: I should warn you though, that DURING deployment (which inclusive of build phase and deploy phase) - the whole server will be unavailable during the deploy phase. If you have done a few tricks here and there according to the documentation - you can reduce the deploy phase to 1-2 minutes. But there will always be downtime during a deployment. Sorry if I didn't make this clear before.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I ve already seen some few tricks to deploy but can you give me a list of them ?
And when you said downtime, just to be sure what it means : 
the website won t be accessible by any customers ? 
Do I need a maintenance page ? Thx a lot for your help :)